# How to trigger a function in SIM800C Module using an SMS from AWS IOT?

Tags: mqtt, gsm, arduino

I am using a SIM800C Module with AWS IoT. I want to be able to trigger some code running on my device by sending an SMS from AWS.

I can generate the SMS OK, but I'm stuck with how to get this to trigger the code I want to run. I assume I need to generate an interrupt and put my code in an interrupt handler?

In that case, how do I generate the interrupt?

Comment: Why is this tagged mqtt when you talk about using sms?

Comment: What do you mean by triggering an interrupt in the SIM800C?

Comment: @naveen, I edited your question to reflect one of the possible interpretations of what you might be asking. Actually, you're asking the wrong level of detail, and probably don't want an interrupt at all here.

Comment: Where does your code run? On the SIM800C or on an MCU which is interfaced with the SIM800C?

Answer (score 1):

A GSM phone or modem receives messages automatically. Basically you are just retrieving the messages from the memory of the device or SIM card. To select the message storage used to read the messages from, you have to use the 
    "AT+CPMS" command.

For example, to read messages from the SIM card use:
    AT+CPMS="SM"

More details you can find on this [link...](http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/receivesmsat/)